# Very slow matrix transpose operation with CUBLAS

Tags: matrix, cuda, cublas

I'm trying to parallelize a matrix transpose operation using the CUBLAS library (with `cublasSgeam` function).
The output data are correct, but It's taking on average **150 more time** than my CPU version. Why?

**CPU code** (For transposing a matrix of `N = 5000` by `M=140`)

```
// Starting the timer
    float *matrixT = (float *) malloc (N * M * sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            matrixT[(j*N)+i] = matrix[(i*M)+j]; // matrix is obviously filled

//Ending the timer
```

**GPU code** (For transposing a matrix of `N = 5000` by `M=140`)

```
    float *h_matrixT , *d_matrixT , *d_matrix;
    h_matrixT = (float *) malloc (N * M * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_matrixT , N * M * sizeof(float)));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_matrix , N * M * sizeof(float)));
    cudaMemcpy(d_matrix , matrix , N * M * sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

//Starting the timer

    const float alpha = 1.0;
    const float beta  = 0.0;
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasCreate(&handle);
    cublasSgeam(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_N, N, M, &alpha, d_matrix, M, &beta, d_matrix, N, d_matrixT, N);
    cublasDestroy(handle);

//Ending the timer

    cudaMemcpy(h_matrixT , d_matrixT , N * M * sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));


    cudaFree(d_matrix);
    cudaFree(d_matrixT);
```

**Elapsed times**

*CUBLAS  : 148.461 ms*

*CPU     : 0.986944 ms*

**PS:** *Running on GeForce GTX 660 & Intel Core i5 660*

Comment: How large N and M are? Take also into account that you are including the time for creating the cublas context in the timing.

Comment: What happens if you run the transform twice? Is the speed the same the second time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your code with one of the [profilers](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#abstract) to see where the time is being spent.

Move the `cublasCreate` function out of your timing region.  That is picking up all sorts of CUDA and library start up time, which should not be incorporated in benchmarking a single function (or if you intend to benchmark this way, there is obviously little point in using a GPU to perform this one single function.  It will not accelerate it, as you have discovered.)

I would also recommend moving the `cublasDestroy` out of the timing loop.

You may then wish to include a `cudaDeviceSynchronize();` before your final timing closure.

Here's a fully worked example, choosing M = 1000 and N = 1000, with the changes above implemented:

```
$ cat t469.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define uS_PER_SEC 1000000
#define uS_PER_mS 1000
#define N  1000
#define M 1000

int main(){

    timeval t1, t2;
    float *matrix = (float *) malloc (N * M * sizeof(float));
// Starting the timer
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    float *matrixT = (float *) malloc (N * M * sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            matrixT[(j*N)+i] = matrix[(i*M)+j]; // matrix is obviously filled

//Ending the timer
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    float et1 = (((t2.tv_sec*uS_PER_SEC)+t2.tv_usec) - ((t1.tv_sec*uS_PER_SEC)+t1.tv_usec))/(float)uS_PER_mS;
    printf("CPU time = %fms\n", et1);

    float *h_matrixT , *d_matrixT , *d_matrix;
    h_matrixT = (float *) (malloc (N * M * sizeof(float)));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_matrixT , N * M * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_matrix , N * M * sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(d_matrix , matrix , N * M * sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

//Starting the timer
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

    const float alpha = 1.0;
    const float beta  = 0.0;
    // gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasCreate(&handle);
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    cublasSgeam(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_N, N, M, &alpha, d_matrix, M, &beta, d_matrix, N, d_matrixT, N);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    cublasDestroy(handle);

//Ending the timer
    float et2 = (((t2.tv_sec*uS_PER_SEC)+t2.tv_usec) - ((t1.tv_sec*uS_PER_SEC)+t1.tv_usec))/(float)uS_PER_mS;
    printf("GPU time = %fms\n", et2);

    cudaMemcpy(h_matrixT , d_matrixT , N * M * sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


    cudaFree(d_matrix);
    cudaFree(d_matrixT);
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -O3 -arch=sm_20 -o t469 t469.cu -lcublas
$ ./t469
CPU time = 8.744000ms
GPU time = 0.327000ms
$
```

If instead, I change the above code to leave the timing function start *before* the `cublasCreate` call, I get this:

```
$ ./t469
CPU time = 9.475000ms
GPU time = 78.393997ms
$
```

Comment: You are right, it is cublasCreate function that is taking 99% of the overhead (140 ms !), cublasDetroy (0.24 ms), and finally cublasSgeam (only 0.18 ms = 1 fifth of the CPU time). I think I'm not going to use this library to get rid of this huge overhead. So the best thing to do is to write my own kernel.

Comment: The overhead should only be encountered once per execution of your entire program.  `cublasCreate` is something you do once, in your program.  Furthermore, having incurred the overhead once, you are now free to use other cublas functions in your program without incurring additional library start-up overhead.

Comment: I agree that if the only thing you want to do is do one single matrix transpose, using the GPU is not sensible.  Even if there were no `cublasCreate` overhead, the amount of time spent transferring the data to and from the device would probably wipe out any gains from doing the transpose there.  Using such a function only makes sense in the context of a larger GPU-accelerated application.

Comment: If you choose to write your own matrix transpose you may be interested in [this blog](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/efficient-matrix-transpose-cuda-cc/)

Comment: Actually for a 4096x4096 float matrix, the data copy time (summing both to and from GPU) should be ~30ms.  For a matrix of that size, Sgeam requires about 2ms to do the transpose (so ~32ms total) but the host code in this example (naive, single-threaded) requires ~400ms.  For a square matrix, the blog kernel is easily adaptable as well, and performs a bit faster than the Sgeam function.  So it may not be "crazy" to use the GPU just for transpose, if you compare to a naive host implementation.